# HighCharts--custom redraw handler borks zooming?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to make a column chart in HighCharts with annotations that are properly repositioned whenever the chart is resized or zoomed.

http://jsfiddle.net/2tJ3G/

You can see what I mean by resizing the frame around the chart. The annotations stay where they should be.

The problem only comes about when this redraw function is called from a zoom.. the chart just reloads. I've had some success providing a function for the redraw event, however this has completely broken select-zooming (which just shows all data). Here's my handler:

```
function drawIt() {
    var optionsTmp = options;  
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsTmp, function(chart) {

    var text, box, point;
    var count = 0;
    for (var annotX in annots) {
        var annot = annots[annotX];
        if (annot.length > 0) {
           //draw rectangles / text with annot vals
        }
        count++;
    }
});
options = optionsTmp;
}
```

It's possible I'm not properly passing through the new extremes from the zoom (`options.xAxis.min`) but trying to pass this into the handler hasn't given me much luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, my setExtremes function (which gets called before a total redraw of the chart) was stomping on the feet of the following redraw function. I had to set the thresholds there and silence it early.

```
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                doZoom = true; 
                min= e.min; 
                max = e.max;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
```

Corrected fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9LgUf/1/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to remove chart, and create new one - this is not possible just by setting empty container - you need to also destroy chart. But still this is not possible to destroy chart while redrawing - it will cause errors.

I think you should try another solution, for example updating that annotations. Something similar is done here with extra lines for points, see: http://www.highcharts.com/jsbin/oyadep/4/edit#javascript,live

Of course, it's not finished but works fine when zooming in.

```
function drawPaths(options) {
var maxNum = 2;


//add the paths
group_init = options.renderer.g().add();
// console.log(options);
for (i = 0; i < maxNum; i++) {

    $.each(options.series[i].data, function(i2, point) {
        var xpos = options.xAxis[0].translate(this.x);
        var ypos = options.yAxis[0].translate(this.y, false, true);
        var gr = this.y; //gross revenue
        var p_gr = 0; //for tests
        var eq; //equation
        var my;
        //console.log(this);
        eq = gr + 1; //equation
        my = options.yAxis[0].translate(eq, false, true);
        //console.log(xpos, ypos, my);
        options.renderer.path(['M', xpos + 105, ypos + 5, 'L', xpos + 105, my + 5]).attr({
            'stroke-width': 1,
            stroke: '#ad2b2b'
        }).add(group_init);

    });
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll experiment with destroying the chart before a redraw and recreating it. The solution you linked to unfortunately isn't applicable for what I'm trying to do ( annotations that display strings that are not simply their x or y values). Basic labels for the data points never really had any trouble displaying in the right place after zoom. chart.renderer.rect / chart.renderer.img / etc. do not reposition themselves on a zoom, though.

Comment: Another note--I've found that emptying the chart is sufficient to trigger the redraw. Destroying it in the redraw function will actually trigger the function redraw twice.. and as you said, it'll fail (the second time).

Comment: But have you opened my example and try to run it? As you can see it works properly. I advice you to implement that in the same way as is done.

Comment: I did try implementing this approach, however on a column chart the items rendered do not line up with their original bars on resize of the chart. Maybe there's something I'm missing. I've found a solution to this but I'll hold off on marking it as the answer. thanks for your time